# Save and Access Vectors in a 3D-Matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector

For my project I need to save vectors in a matrix, thus creating a multidimensional array (3D-Matrix).

Now I'm wondering on how to access my vectors.

Lets say I have a lot of vectors stored in an array c. I could access all vectors with `c(i,:)`.
I can also perform vector operations and use buit in fuctions like `norm(c(1,:))`and it gives me the absolute value of the vector. Everythings fine

Now if I store a vector v in a 2D-matrix M, i can still access every element of the vector, but `M(i,j,:)` doesnt give me the output `[vx;vy;vz]`I'm looking for. Instead matlab gives three outputs resulting in problems using the built in vector operations.

Is there any way around this?
Or do I have to implement my own functions to operate on a 3d-matrix?

Edit:
If `z` is a vector, the output is: `z = [zx zy zz]`
If this vetor is stored in a 2x2x3 matrix `M(2,2,3)`, lets say in `M(1,1)`, the output when accessing the vector by `M(1,1,:)`isnt `[zx zy zz]`.

Instead the output is: `M(:,:,1) = zx` `M(:,:,2) = zy` `M(:,:,3) = zz`

Thanks for pointing out to change the direction the vector is stored in the matrix.

Comment: It's unclear why `M(i,j,:)` would give you _"three outputs"_, please provide a [mcve] by [edit]ing your question. Do you mean the output is of size `[1,1,n]`? Maybe you're looking for the `squeeze` function to collapse the first two dimensions

Comment: You should store your vectors in the matrix as columns instead of rows. In particular, the first dimension should be where the vectors are. That way each vector's elements are contiguous in memory (faster access), and you avoid the need for the squeeze( ) function when you extract them for use. E.g., extracting a vector should look like M(:,m,n) and not M(m,n,:). The colon should be in the first dimension.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I didn't know this decision could affect perfomance as well. Always helpful to get this inside.

Answer (score 0):

`M(i,j,:)` returns a 1×1×3 array, which Matlab understand is not exactly a vector `v` as you want, but a three-dimensional array, which happens to have only one element with respect to the first and second indices.

You can easily remove the dimensions of length 1 with the built-in function [squeeze](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html):

```
A = zeros(1,1,3);
A(:,:,1:3) = [1 2 3]
```

> ```
> A = 
> A(:,:,1) =
>
>      1
>
>
> A(:,:,2) =
>
>      2
>
>
> A(:,:,3) =
>
>      3
> ```

```
B = squeeze(A)
```

> ```
> B = 3×1
>
>      1
>      2
>      3
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know that function existed, that wouldve easily solved the problem.
However as @jamestursa mentioned, switching the order of storing the vector also did the trick ^^